# Geo-Autocomplete for a certain country

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I would like to have an input field on my website with autocomplete for places within a certain country. For example in the code below I want to get only places within the country 'The Netherlands' as suggestions in the autocomplete.

In the code below I'm getting suggestions for places in all countries, not specified for a certain country.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Places Autocomplete</title>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"
  type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  #map_canvas {
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    margin-top: 0.6em;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {

    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {country: 'NL'});

    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
      }

    });

    setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
  <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
  <label for="changetype-all"></label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a bias (which you already have) but without actually checking each autocomplete result with additional code you cannot limit the autocomplete list to a certain country or area, to my knowledge.

Here is some more information on Google's Autocomplete: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html#place_autocomplete_requests

Ah, if you want to use the geo-autocomplete plugin, then take a look at this example:

view-source:http://geo-autocomplete.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/ui.demo.html

This is from their example:

```
$('#demo3_location').geo_autocomplete({
    geocoder_region: 'Africa',
    geocoder_types: 'country',
    mapheight: 100, mapwidth: 200, maptype: 'hybrid'
});
```

Comment: On this link: http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/ it says: geocoder_region ==> Filter suggested locations to a specific region, e.g. 'Europe' that's why I thought it should be possible.. I also tried it with geocoder_region

Comment: geo-autocomplete requires an additional plugin. I've udpated my answer with their demo which uses geocoder_region to give you a more absolute filter.

Comment: That example is not working (both FF and IE) I also tried your code  with id: "searchTextField" but also not working..

Comment: I found a working example:

http://honestbleeps.com/demos/jQuery-autocomplete-with-json-and-geonames/

Answer (score 2):

No need to change anything - you just have to create a Global variable option instead of 
`{country: 'NL'}` 
put `options` at there.
Now declare Option before use.

```
options = {types: ['(cities)'],componentRestrictions: { country: 'US' }};
```

Now Your line will be:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Hope work for you - !
Thanks,
Kavi (India)